# mysql_error(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.0

Im using this script to load csv file to mysql :

```
$sql = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$target_file."' 
                                INTO TABLE tbl_avaibility FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                                OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                                IGNORE 1 LINES
                                (name, total_downtime, mttr, mtbf, uptimepercentage, grup, periode, trim, cek, key1, grouptype, groupname, iphost, ha, tier, manage, sec, min, hour, downtime, cekpercentage, test, status, ipvm, namevm, statevm, hostvm, cluster, vcenter, cekcok) SET nik_user='$user_id'");

if(!$sql)
{
    mysql_error($sql);
}
```

In my newest mysql its working.

In my server which is old version of mysql, mysql 5.0 its give me an error when i upload a file.

mysql_error(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource

Can somebody tell me what to do.

Comment: Just fyi, [mysql_query](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is deprecated. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Its work because i could do a normal insert update delete in there.

Comment: Query is also vulnerable to sql injection. I hope this code isn't in production somewhere.

Comment: `mysql_error()` returns the error, if any, so you need to `echo` it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't feed `mysql_error()` your `mysql_query()` result ($sql), either leave it null, or feed it the resource link from `mysql_connect()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

```
string mysql_error ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

In this example, `$link_identifier` is optional, change your code to this...

```
if(!$sql)
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Im using mysql error to see its error, before this i use javascript alert, which is also not working.

Comment: That is irrelevent?

Comment: Seems like its solve 1 problem, the error gone and now show the real error. But i still cant get it work because file is not found (Errcode: 2)

Comment: I'd be guessing a permission error where by your MySQL process can't access that location in the file system. Try copying `$target_file` to a `/tmp` folder? This is going to need a new thread at any rate. Good that you have the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` part correct though.